# Prompt message while trying to open an excel file

Tags: c#, excel, io

I have a code that open an Excel file and read the content. Each time i run the code for the first time, it opens the Excel file without prompting me. But from the second time going it always prompt me this message

**TestFile.xlsx is being modified by user 1. Open as read only**

and it always prompt at this portion of the code:

```
Excel ._Workbook  xlsBook = xlsApp .Workbooks.Open (_fileName,0,false,5 ,"","",false ,Excel .XlPlatform .xlWindows ,"",true ,false ,0,true ,false ,false );
```

**NB: i also close the file after the operation done and also using VS 2012**

So what can be the problem of this prompt ??

Comment: You open the file once, and because it isn't shared, when you try to open it again you can only open it as read-only because only one user at a time can edit it. Perhaps creating a shared Excel file will help you. (Basics of Excel)

Comment: Do you open the file a second time? or did you close the file first. If you closed the file and you get this message, it might be a timing problem (especially if the file is located on a file server) where the (just recently) closed file has not yet been released. Can you live with read-only? otherwise try adding a pause to provide time for the file to be released.

Answer (score 0):

After running your Code and exiting, look in the taskmanager, most likely die EXCEL.EXE instance is still running.

you most likely didn't release all the com objects like:

```
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_theWorkbook);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_sheets);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_workSheet);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_range);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_excelObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no resources where the file would be still opened. Could you post the code you're using to close the resource? Perhaps there's an error there.

Finally, as ugly as it is, it's valid for testing purposes: try manually calling the garbage collector after closing the file.

FINALLY, consider using the OpenXml API to work with Excel/Word files, as opposed to the Interop DLLs (remember these require the client to have Excel installed, as opposed to the OpenXml libraries which you can deploy with your application).